# Can i group a text file with Regex based on line patterns

Tags: c#, regex

Given a file:

```
Timestamp: some text and a number 1
Timestamp: some text and a number 33
Timestamp: some text and a number 1
Timestamp: some text and a number 22
Something totally different, maybe a new pattern
Timestamp: some text and a number 4
Timestamp: some text and a number 2
Something totally different, maybe a new pattern
Something totally different, maybe a new pattern
```

I would like to get groupings of line 1 to 4(TYPE1) and line 5(TYPE2), line 6,7(TYPE1) and line 8,9(TYPE2).

Can this be done in one regualar expression or should i create one expression for each type and then check line by line and if the previous line is the same type?

At the end i need to return a list of groupings with pair(int start_char, int end_char)

Comment: Do you want to group *all* or only sequential items of a group?  (Ie, are you looking for 4 groups, or just 2 here?)

Comment: I am looking for 4 groups in this example. I want to fold the text into groups that are similar. Where the similarity is based on if a regex pattern match for current line and previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("your taext file");

       var Groups =( 
                from w in lines 
                group w by w[0] into g 
                select new { FirstLetterLine = g.Key, Lins = g });
```

Comment: I might use something like this, could create a method for the group by to seperate lines into a group.